How to update the background color of a cell in an ALV grid?
I have an editable ALV Grid managed via CL_GUI_ALV_GRID. I have defined a cell background color in the color table of each line and that color is displaying correctly. Now I would like to update the color of a cell during the handling of event data_changed (turn the cell from red to green if the changed data is valid). However the background color is not changing.
I have tried these 3 solutions in the method that handles the event data_changed:

Call method er_data_changed->modify_cell and passing it the modified color table.
Directly changing the internal table passed to the ALV Grid.
Changing the color table on the appropriate row in er_data_changed->mp_mod_rows->.

None of it worked.
There is a method er_data_changed->modify_style but no method er_data_changed->modify_color.
Thank you.

There is a refresh method of the ALV, shouldn't it be called as well? It would be great if you could post your code, i. e. a reproducable example.

Thanks, calling the refresh method, after changing the ALV internal table, worked. Please post your comment as an answer so I can close the question.

The ALV class has to have a REFRESH method (or something similar method name, for example by CL_GUI_ALV_GRID it is the method REFRESH_TABLE_DISPLAY). This method has to be called as well, to refresh the ALV output.

FYI calling REFRESH_TABLE_DISPLAY will not update the cell color if the parameter is_stable is set to true and the ALV table has been scrolled down.

I know calling the refresh_table_display method in the handle_data_changed event works and is the most straight forward solution. But I want to warn you: Doing this can break a lot of things so you should avoid this if possible.
For example (the most prominent side effect): It clears fields that have an error protocol. This is because fields with an error protocol are not send to the table that the refresh is using to set the new data.
If you need a refresh here, it's always better to call the refresh in the handle_data_changed_finished
event, when E_MODIFIED is set. That way you only refresh, when there are no errors you'd overwrite otherwise.
So you can use the modify_cell method in handle_data_changed on your color table field and have the refresh in handle_data_changed_finished

I've had the problem you're describing, thanks, I'll test your solution.
